# using PostGIS to intersect a csv table with a county shapefile

Tags: csv, postgis, shapefile, intersect

Hi I have a csv table name texas and a county shapefile name txcounty.shp

i tried to useing the following to get the points which intersects the txcounty.shp. but its not working.

```
CREATE TABLE txintect as (
    SELECT DISTINCT ST_Intersection (texas.the_geom, txcounty.the_geom)    
FROM
    texas_geometries AS texas,
    txcounty_geometies AS txcounty
    WHERE texas.name='Hutchinson' 
    AND ST_Overlaps(texas.the_geom, txcounty.the_geom)
);
```

Comment: To perform spatial intersections you need spatial data... csv is not a spatial data. Also - it's difficult to help you when you didn't provide stacktrace (what error you're getting). DDL-s of this tables also could be handy. Without additional data all help will be only blind shots...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have imported shapefile and csv in the database, have you tried the function ST_intersects instead of ST_Overlaps